# VueJs: Textarea input binding

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to figure out how to detect change of the value on the textarea from within the component.

For input we can simply use

```
<input
  :value="value"
  @input="update($event.target.value)"
>
```

However on textarea this won't work.

What I'm working with is the CKEditor component, which should update wysiwyg's content when model value of the parent component (attached to this child component) is updated.

My `Editor` component currently looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="editor" :class="groupCss">
        <textarea :id="id" v-model="input"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            value: {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: 'editor'
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                input: this.$slots.default ? this.$slots.default[0].text : '',
                config: {
                    ...
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            input(value) {
                this.update(value);
            }
        },
        methods: {
            update(value) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[this.id].setData(value);
            },
            fire(value) {
                this.$emit('input', value);
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            CKEDITOR.replace(this.id, this.config);
            CKEDITOR.instances[this.id].setData(this.input);
            this.fire(this.input);
            CKEDITOR.instances[this.id].on('change', () => {
                this.fire(CKEDITOR.instances[this.id].getData());
            });
        },
        destroyed () {
            if (CKEDITOR.instances[this.id]) {
                CKEDITOR.instances[this.id].destroy()
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

and I include it within the parent component

```
<html-editor
    v-model="fields.body"
    id="body"
></html-editor>
```

however, whenever parent component's model value changes - it does not trigger the watcher - effectively not updating the editor's window.

I only need `update()` method to be called when parent component's model `fields.body` is updated.

Any pointer as to how could I approach it?

Comment: vue textarea value just using `v-model` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Multiline-text

Answer (score 5):

That's a fair bit of code to decipher, but what I would do is break down the text area and the WYSIWYG HTML window into two distinct components and then have the parent sync the values, so:

**TextArea Component:**

```
<template id="editor">
  <textarea :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
</template>

/**
 *  Editor TextArea
 */
Vue.component('editor', {
  template: '#editor',
  props: {
    value: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    }
  }
});
```

All I'm doing here is emitting the input back to the parent when it changes, I'm using input as the event name and `value` as the prop so I can use `v-model` on the editor. Now I just need a wysiwyg window to show the code:

**WYSIWYG Window:**

```
/**
 * WYSIWYG window
 */
Vue.component('wysiwyg', {
  template: `<div v-html="html"></div>`,
  props: {
    html: {
      default: '',
      type: String
    }
  }
});
```

Nothing much going on there, it simply renders the HTML that is passed as a prop.

Finally I just need to sync the values between the components:

```
<div id="app">
  <wysiwyg :html="value"></wysiwyg>
  <editor v-model="value"></editor>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: '<b>Hello World</b>'
  }
})
```

Now, when the editor changes it emits the event back to the parent, which updates `value` and in turn fires that change in the wysiwyg window. Here's the entire thing in action: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnpmbpcr/

Comment: Thanks @craig_h - I'll give it a try

Comment: Hmm - I don't think it's going to work as wysiwyg also needs to emit `input` when it's content is being updated - at the moment it would only update `wysiwyg` when you type into `editor`, which I'm afraid is not what I'm after. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ah OK, in that case I would suggest you look at [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org) so you can extract out the shared state, rather than trying to emit and sync the state across components yourself.

Comment: I've ended up using Event Handler - when parent model changes, I fire event - which is catched from within the editor - then the update is performed.